# Kill me or I kill you first!

Tags: no-computers, chess

> ***How many mates are possible under 10 moves?***

**Rule:**

- Mate can go both ways.
- Under 10 moves.
- Feel free to let White or Black move first.

Board diagram:

[image]

[Apronus PGN Viewer](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?p=AKB__Q__rp____P_Ppp___pPp_n____p_N_______PPq____B_P_____b_k___N_R0) board for white taking the first move.

[Apronus PGN Viewer](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?s=black&p=AKB__Q__rp____P_Ppp___pPp_n____p_N_______PPq____B_P_____b_k___N_R0) board for black taking the first move.

<sub>My first puzzle here. Hope I tagged it right and enjoyable for you guys :)</sub>

Clarification to [Glorfindel answer question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/85562/1/) "I'm not sure how you define 'different' mates - is that the key move only?":

> In this question specifically, "Mate" refers to key moves which would be resulting mates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few to begin with. I'm not sure how you define 'different' mates - is that the key move only?

Mate in 1, White to move:

> 1. a7#
>  1. Nd7#

Mate in 1, Black to move:

> 1... b2#

Mate in 2, White to move:

> 1. Nxc6+, Ne6+, Ng6+, Nxh7+, Qe8+, Qe5+, Bf4+ and mate on the next move by 2. a7#

Mate in 2, Black to move:

> 1... Qf6+ 2. Qe5 Qxe5# or 2. Qc3 Qxc3#
>  1... axb1Q+ (or 1... axb1R+) 2. Qxb1 Rxb1#